# Why doesn't jqGrid cellattr style seem to work in IE 7 (but works fine in IE8 and FF)

Tags: jquery, css, jqgrid

i use the following code in my jqgrid colmodel:

```
cellattr: function (rowId, tv, rawObject, cm, rdata) { return 'style="background-color:LightGray"'; },
```

which works perfect in Firefox and IE8 (see image):

[image]

but in IE7 it doesn't seem to work as the backcolor stays white:

[image]

here is an example of the html that gets generated when i do view current selection source:

```
<td role="gridcell" style="text-align: right; background-color: LightGray;" title="199,458" aria-describedby="treegrid_dealsCurrent">
```

doesn't anyone know if this is a bug in jqgrid or if there is something specific you need to do in IE7 to get this working ?

Comment: @Fender - i posted some html if that is what you are looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tested with

```
cellattr: function (rowId, tv, rawObject, cm, rdata) { return 'style="background:LightGray"'; }
```

I.e. with just "background".

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem: **cellatr** was working with chrome and Firefox but not with IE8 or IE9.
Solution for me was to **add a space before the style**:

```
return ' style="background-color:LightGreen;color:LightGreen;" '
```

Cheers